# Spring security POST method throwing 403 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am building a user registration form. I have `POST` endpoint for registration and  I am able to successfully register.

I have another endpoint called `/invalid-token` which is also mappped to `POST` mapping. I have added both of the endpoints to `permitAll` rules as below:

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers(
         "/register",
         "/confirm",
         "/invalid-token",
         "/registration-success")
     .permitAll()
     .anyRequest()
     .authenticated();
```

When I make a `POST` request to the `invalid-token` from the browser, I am getting a `403`. I am not understanding where I am going wrong.

```
Response Status:
        General:
        Request URL: http://localhost:8081/invalid-token
        Request Method: POST
        Status Code: 403 
        Remote Address: [::1]:8081
        Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade



  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
   Content-Length: 0
   Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2019 05:14:30 GMT
   Expires: 0
   Pragma: no-cache
   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   X-Frame-Options: DENY
   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: Can you check what is the [sub status error code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) ?

Comment: Did you try disabling CSRF? `http.csrf().disable();`? If it works, consider adding a token to production, disabling it is only for checking, dev...

Comment: When I disable CSRF, it works, but why is the `/register` endpoint working even without `csrf` disabled

Comment: @Maroun Iam curious to know, why it works for `register` endpoint and not for `/invalid-token` endpoint with disabled `csrf`.

Comment: @zilcuanu I'm not really sure. Can you provide more code? Or the way you're trying to access the resources?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to follow standard API definitions when defining micro services.

Issue could be the pattern you have defined i.e. `/invalid-token`

CSRF `disable` worked because in your API URL the pattern `/invalid-token` has special character which I guess allowed by SpringSecurity.

When CSRF is enabled than some how `-` is causing spring security to mark it as 403.

You can try with pattern `/invalid/token` and even with CSRF enabled and it should get required behaviour.

Comment: This challenged my spring skills and was overwhelming. Is the spdical character behavior   mentioned in the docs?

Comment: The special character in URL is a general issue irrespective of Spring Security which fails in mapping resolvers. Can you try defining some regex may be?